# Exporting diffs without having to commit in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, export, diff

I am using TortoiseHg GUI and it seems that there is no way to export diffs between my uncommited changes and the last revision. Is there a way to do it using hg ?

My requirements :

- I do not want to commit my changes
- I could copy the whole directory, commit, export, delete but the directory is quite heavy

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. You could commit your changes, choose Export -> Export Patch from the context menu of the changeset and then rollback (Repository -> Rollback/Undo)
2. Alternatively, you could select all the uncommitted changes and then choose the Copy Patch option in the context menu. This copies a patch for all your changes to your clipboard. Then open up your favourite text editor and paste the contents into the new buffer and save this as a patch.

Comment: I did not realized that Copy Patch was copying to the clipboard... Using this plus a syntax highlighter for diff code solved my problem, thanks !

Answer (score 5):

It can be done very simply by a patch file via

> hg diff > foo.patch

Then the patch can be applied on the other repo via

> hg import --no-commit foo.patch

Answer (score 3):

From the command line `hg diff` will show the differences in the repository using the unified diff format.